# WPF Clipping Problem

Tags: wpf, clipping

I have a UserControl which has a quadratic Image as a Child. This Image is at the bottom of the UserControl, and half of it is clipped (e.g. the Control's Height is 400, Image's height is 200 and it is set to y=300).

Now, When I rotate the Image, it is still clipped like the way it was first. Like when rotating around 90 degrees, I suddenly have an Image which is only 100px wide.

It seems like the original clipping which was made because of the bounds of the UserControl, are applied forever.

How do I solve this problem? I hope I explained my problem understandable ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How are you rotating the image?  If you are rotating using a [RenderTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx), then WPF does not re-render what was already displayed on the screen - it simply rotates the pixels.

Instead, rotate the image using a [LayoutTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform.aspx); this forces WPF to re-render the control given the new area it occupies, which should eliminate the clipping you see.

Comment: You just saved my boss and I a day's worth of work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also call `InvalidateMeasure()` after applying render transform.